# C# program stops processing while making Web Request

Tags: c#, webrequest

I'm very new to C# and am playing around with writing a basic program. The goal is to grab an image and save it to the disk given a URL.

This is where my code essentially times out:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(m.Value.Trim()); // url string passed in from Regex function
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse) req.GetResponse(); // times out here
```

The code is in a class containing one function, which runs as such:

```
 String url; // passed in as a parameter
 String folder = @"C:\SMBC";
 // create directory if not exists to save comic
 if(!Directory.Exists(folder)) 
     Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);

     // visit the site and check for comics
     HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
     request.Method = "GET";
     HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
     using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                // if line contains "/comics/" then I'm in the right spot, we're at a URL now
                String line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (line.Contains("/comics/"))
                {
                    // pull out the address of the image // example result: http://www.smbc-comics.com/comics/20020905-2.gif
                    Regex linkParser = new Regex(@"\b(?:https?://|www\.)\S+\b", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    foreach (Match m in linkParser.Matches(line))
                    {
                        // new local file in folder, use original file name
                        String name = @"" + folder +"\\" + m.Value.Substring(m.Value.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                        Console.WriteLine(m.Value.Trim()); //http://www.smbc-comics.com/comics/20020905-2.gif
                        Uri uri = new Uri(m.Value.Trim());
                        
                        Console.WriteLine("Making request"); // works 
                        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(m.Value.Trim());
                        Console.WriteLine("getting response"); // works
                        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse) req.GetResponse();
                        Console.WriteLine("opening stream"); // never shows
                        using (Stream inputStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
                        using (Stream outputStream = File.OpenWrite(name))
                        {
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                            int bytesRead;
                            do
                            {
                                bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                                outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            } while (bytesRead != 0);
                            //outputStream.Close();
                            //inputStream.Close();
                            //resp.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I am running this in the console and here's what I get:

[image]

After a while, the operation just times out, I know that the address is valid, because I visit it.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: I don't think so, why? I'm able to see the image if I paste the url into my browser.

Comment: Using your code verbatim with the url of front page of the site in question, I get 2 successful download and saves.

Comment: hmm.. odd, thanks for looking at it @spender

Comment: If you are on a corporate network, you're likely behind a proxy. If you were behind a proxy, you would have to provide the proxy information to your code in order to visit the page. If your code is tested and it works, I would guess there is an issue with your network connection.

Comment: Do you receieve a response in fiddler ?

Comment: I don't buy the proxy thing because the first request goes through no problem. Does your code make hits on the domain in question that you haven't documented in your question? I notice that you're not closing/disposing the response in your loop... maybe you're hitting the servicepoint connection limit?

Comment: @spender, I make one previous request to the domain (the archives page) which contains a list of URLs. Each of the URLs in that list are visited by looping through and executing the above code. I'm unsure what Servicepoint connection limit is (again I'm really new to C#)

Comment: So essentially, the first connection in this code, is the second connection for the system, then the third connection is that of getting the Image

Comment: @spender, thanks for the info, I looked into the connection limit and set it to 4, now the code executes fine! ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 4;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're hitting the [`ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.connectionlimit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This can be increased by tweaking `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` before you start. Don't forget to `.Dispose` of everything that can be disposed in the smallest possible scope... `using` statements are good. If you don't close/dispose of `WebRequest` related stuff, you can eat into your connection limit even if you believe that the request is finished.

Answer (score 1):

As a newbie, I was unaware that the framework let a limit on the number of connections allowed at any given time.

So you have to override this in case you have loops within loops of connections.

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 4;
```